# How do you C++ Vector init in header construct to fill with pointers of a static char const

Tags: c++, pointers, header-files

header file:

```cpp
#include<vector>

#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int s) : pegs (s, *TOKEN_EMPTY){}
    static char const TOKEN_EMPTY=' ';

protected:
    std::vector<char*> pegs;
}
```

When trying to build I get the error:

```
error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘char’)
   20 |  Foo(int s) : pegs (s, *TOKEN_EMPTY){}
```

In case it isn't clear, I just want to initialize a C++ vector of pointers that point to a `static char const` variable.

I'm still checking StackOverflow and online, but I am hopeful someone can help me or lead me in the right direction!

Comment: Are you wanting a vector of pointers to `char` or a vector of `char`? If it's the latter, changing `std::vector<char*>` to `std::vector<char>` and removing the `*` from `*TOKEN_EMPTY` should do the trick.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to do a vector of pointers that point to a char.

Comment: I changed to &TOKEN_EMPTY.  I am from a different language and not used to pointers I still have plenty of errors but I believe it will still fail.

Answer (score 1):

Adding few more points in the answer provided by @Roger.

- `*TOKEN_EMPTY` is incorrect syntax, what you need is address of `TOKEN_EMPTY` so you need to apply `&` operator to get address of the variable.
- the `TOKEN_EMPTY` is `const char` string, so when you apply `&` operator, it would return `const char*`. So you need to update your vector to hold `const char *`.
- Alternatively you can also use typecast operation to convert `const char *` to `char *` but it could possibly lead to issues where you can potentially modify the value of `const char`.

Here is a sample code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int s) : pegs (s, &TOKEN_EMPTY){}
    static char const TOKEN_EMPTY=' ';

protected:
    std::vector<const char*> pegs;
};

int main() {
    // ues class Foo
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did something like a class pointer char * pAlpha=const_cast<char *>(&ALPHA_TEAM); and made pegs[0]=pAlpha and the like.  But I will probably change it to the vector version.... again not my starting language and I've read what I could on pointers and const... the pegs change from token_empty to other tokens so I feel complications by having the pointers const char.  but that may be my ignorance.  I missed my deadline as I ran into another probelm.  But I get 50% for today so maybe I can figure it out lol Thank you for the answer!! I have trouble getting answers often!!

Answer (score 0):

Changed to `&TOKEN_EMPTY` and had to use:

```cpp
std::vector<const char*> pegs;
```

Comment: If you need to add non-const `char*` elements to the vector after the constructor exits, you can remove the `const` in the `vector` and `const_cast` the static `char` in the constructor, eg: `std::vector<char*> pegs; ... Foo(int s) : pegs (s, const_cast<char*>(&TOKEN_EMPTY)){}`

Comment: In C and C++, a pointer to `char` _typically_ represents a NULL-terminated string (that is an arbitrary number of characters, that end at the first `0x00` byte. Your solution breaks with that convention and _could_ cause problems. I suggest you do: `static char const* TOKEN_EMPTY=" ";` which will make `TOKEN_EMPTY` a proper null-terminated string. Once you do that, you will find that you no longer need to use the ["address of" operator `&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) in front of `TOKEN_EMPTY`, since it will now be a pointer.